# Android OpenGL ES2 Texture gets swapped on desire s

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, textures

I am making a game which I develop on the Nexus 4, it runs fine and no problems. I tested it on Sony's Xperia U and (for this problem) it runs fine as well.
The problem however is on the desire S (with the same code)

When I start the actual gameplay I have this background texture that should be rendered but for a second or so it takes the wrong texture. See the effect:

Image of Issue swap:

[image]

The left picture is what goes wrong, the right picture is how it should be (not exactly the same time but it is for the visualisation of my problem).

It takes the texture that is assigned to GLES20.GL_TEXTURE4 where it should have taken GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0.

Before I go to the code, something same happens during gameplay, whenever particles are rendered my text (also textures) are swapped with different textures. The moment my particles are gone, the text is rendered correctly again.

Image of Issue swap:

[image]

In this example it seems to take the texture that holds my background but it is random, because i do remember seeing only characters as well but then with black backgrounds and no transparency. The particles and the text engine use the same ShaderProgram, the background however does not, but for completeness, my shader:

```
public static final String vertexShaderCodeTC =
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
    "attribute vec4 a_Color;" +
    "attribute vec2 a_texCoord;" +
    "varying vec4 v_Color;" + 
    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
    "  v_texCoord = a_texCoord;" +
    "  v_Color = a_Color;" + 
    "}";
public static final String fragmentShaderCodeTC =
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "varying vec4 v_Color;" +
    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
    "uniform sampler2D s_texture;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord ) * v_Color;" +
    "  gl_FragColor.rgb *= v_Color.a;" +
    "}";
```

Now here is my rendering code:

```
int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.ShaderProgram, "vPosition");
    riGlobal.checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation | vposition |");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    riGlobal.checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");

    // Prepare the background coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3,
                                 GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                 0, vertexBuffer);
    riGlobal.checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");

    int mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.ShaderProgram, "a_texCoord" );
    riGlobal.checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation | a_texCoord");

    // Prepare the texturecoordinates
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
            false, 
            0, textureBuffer);
    riGlobal.checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mPositionHandle );
    riGlobal.checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLoc );
    riGlobal.checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");


    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(riGraphicTools.ShaderProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    riGlobal.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, m, 0);
    riGlobal.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (riGraphicTools.ShaderProgram, "s_texture" );
    riGlobal.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    // Set the sampler texture unit to 0
    GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLoc, riGlobal.get().getThemeStateOne());
    riGlobal.checkGlError("glUniform1i");

    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, GameBackground.indices.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
    riGlobal.checkGlError("glDrawElements");

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    riGlobal.checkGlError("glDisableVertexAttribArray");
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);
    riGlobal.checkGlError("glDisableVertexAttribArray");
```

When I debug, my themestate function return the correct texture value so it should render my background (as it does on all other devices) but somehow it does not on the Desire S.

This is probably not all the code you need but I do not know exactly what you need and posting my whole app seems somewhat overkill, so please ask and I will explain etc.

I have tested this on multiple devices as stated so it really seems a Desire S only, or some config/setting that just affects the Desire S but I can't seem to find out what, does anybody has any idea or suggestion how to get it rendering correctly again?

P.S. The logic i see is that when I render my red blocks (effect) at start (and end for that matter) it swaps the background texture somehow, as soon as I do not render any triangles with that red block texture anymore, the background renders correctly again. The same i see with particles, rendering them messes up the text. The strange thing here though is that the particle texture is on the same texture as my background, so during gameplay without particles it already draws from that texture.

Also, it only happens on those two places/instances in all parts of my game/menus/parts/etc.

Comment: I have sort of solved the issue by creating seperate shader programs for both the text as for the background, now it works like it should. However why can't I use the same shader for multiple rendering calls? It should right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem, it was a bug in the driver software of the GPU, the textureunit id was only taking once, more info: http://androidblog.reindustries.com/hack-bad-gpu-fix-not-using-correct-texture-opengl/